# How can I draw a commutative diagram without the arrows overlapping?

Tags: tikz-cd

I am trying to draw a commutative diagram as follows.

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& P \arrow[d, "\pi_i" near start]  &\\
& P_i \arrow[u, "\iota_i" near start] \arrow[d, "\phi" near start] & \\ 
M \arrow[r, "\psi"]&N \arrow[r] & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the parallel arrows overlap causing the diagram to look bad.

[image]

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `shift left` and `shift right` keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& P \arrow[d, "\pi_i" near start,shift left=0.75ex]  &\\
& P_i \arrow[u, "\iota_i" near start,shift left=0.75ex] \arrow[d, "\phi" near start] & \\ 
M \arrow[r, "\psi"]&N \arrow[r] & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]